# scp does not honor .ssh/config

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, scp, openssh

Used for a few years **arcfour** as default cipher for SSH2 connection in my *~/.ssh/config* file

```
host namaka
    hostname localhost
    port 2022
    ciphers arcfour
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/virtualbox
    compression true
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    user kermit
```

After an upgrade to Debian 8 I have discovered this cipher has been disabled from default ssh configuration and I was getting the following error

```
no matching cipher found: client arcfour server aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

So I changed my *~/.ssh/config* to

```
host namaka
    hostname localhost
    port 2022
    ciphers aes256-ctr
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/virtualbox
    compression true
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    user kermit
```

(notice the cipher aes256) and now my ssh connection are working again.

```
kermit@euroforce:~$ ssh kermit@namaka

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Jul 16 00:20:21 2015 from 10.0.2.2
kermit@namaka:~$
```

Unfortunately I am still getting the **no matching cipher** error when I try to do an scp

```
kermit@euroforce:~$ scp foo  kermit@namaka:/tmp/
no matching cipher found: client arcfour server aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
lost connection
```

It seems scp has cached somewhere the previous cipher and does not want to use the new one.

Forcing the cipher from command line does work

```
kermit@euroforce:~$ scp -c aes256-ctr foo  kermit@namaka:/tmp/foo2
foo                                                                 100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

Forcing the config file does not work

```
kermit@euroforce:~$ scp -C .ssh/config foo  kermit@namaka:/tmp/foo2
no matching cipher found: client arcfour server aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
lost connection
```

Any clue?

Comment: The flag to pass a config file is `-F`, not `-C`. (Don't know why it's not picking it up by default though.)

Comment: Try running scp with `-vvv`; that should tell you why it does that.

Comment: There you go [link](http://pastebin.com/TEzniSkv): even with `-F` the result does not change

Comment: Why do you want to force the cipher at all? arcfour has been removed for security reasons.

Comment: I want to use a "lightweight" cipher to speed up my connection (especially when forwarding a X session). By the way: I am not asking help to use arcfour, I am asking why, even if I removed arcfour from my config, scp tries to use it (instead of aes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the culprit: it was a bash alias I created a few years ago and then forgot

`alias scp='scp -c arcfour'`

Shame on me

Comment: How funny -- turns out I had done the same thing, only for ssh. I added it years ago to speed up local X11 forwarding.

Comment: Using `~/bin/scp` being a symlink to `ssh-ident` didn't help either.